# Prove that there is an integer a such that a is a primitive root modulo p^2 and a is relatively prime to n. [Hint: Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.]

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number, let $p$ be a prime, and suppose $p^2 \mid n$. Prove that there is an integer $a$ such that $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p^2$ and $a$ is relatively prime to $n$. [Hint: Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.]

Comment: What difficulty are you having with this exercise?

Comment: I don't know how to use Chinese reminder theorem to prove this theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The proof can be broken down into two parts, prove there is a primitive root mod $p^2$ (call it $r$).

Sketch of proof for the first part:

For the first part take a primitive root $\bmod p$ called $x$(One must exist because $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field and the the multiplicative groups of fields are cyclic. If $x$ is not a primitive root $\bmod p$ then $(x+p)$ must be a primitive root.

---

Assuming you already know there is a primitive root $\bmod p^2$ we can proceed to the other part.

Clearly $p$ does not divide $r$ for $r$ is a primitive root.

Now let $n=p^k\cdot b$ where $p\nmid a$

by the Chinese remainder theorem there is a solution to the system of congruences:

$a\equiv r \bmod p^k$

$a\equiv 1 \bmod b$

Since $p^2$ divides $n$ we conclude  $k\geq 2$ and so $a$ is in fact congruent to $r \bmod p^2$ and therefore a primitive root $\bmod p^2$.

on the other hand $p$ does not divide $r$ and $b$ is relatively prime to $a$, so $a$ is relatively prime to $n$, therefore $a$ is the desired integer.

Comment: Thank you very much. But could you please explain a little bit about "b is in fact congruent to 4 mod p^2 and therefore a primitive root mod p^2."

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo,  I fixed it.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!